# NDSolve backward in time

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to integrate ODE from time -100 to 100. I am not able to integrate for a negative time. But, I can integrate until time -2. Even though I get the trajectory for time -2 to 100, the backward time trajectory is wrong. Below is my Mathematica NoteBook.
Thank you

```
subfig1 = 
  Show[solfwd1 = NDSolve[{9680.431963502455*Sin[2.*\[Theta][t]]*Sin[2.*\[Phi][t]] == 1250.*(41.569219381653056*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] - 
          5.7546036633359625*(2.*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]*(3.*Cos[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] - 2.*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]) - 
            10.*Derivative[2][\[Theta]][t])), 2.6179938779914944*(Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*(8.*Cos[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] - 2.*Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]) + 
          5.*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[2][\[Phi]][t]) == -0.0018911460844371192*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*(1895. - 1863.*Cos[2.*\[Phi][t]] + 5000.*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t]), 
       5.235987755982989*(-1.*Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + Cos[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[2][\[Phi]][t] + Derivative[2][\[Psi]][t]) == 
        -5.0684991847974805*(0.379*Cos[\[Theta][t]] + Cos[\[Theta][t]]*Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]), \[Phi][0] == Pi/4, \[Theta][0] == Pi/4, \[Psi][0] == 0, 
       Derivative[1][\[Phi]][0] == 0, Derivative[1][\[Theta]][0] == 0, Derivative[1][\[Psi]][0] == 0}, {\[Theta][t], \[Phi][t], \[Psi][t]}, {t, -100, 100}]; 
    ParametricPlot3D[{Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Cos[\[Phi][t]], Sin[\[Theta][t]]*Sin[\[Phi][t]], Cos[\[Theta][t]]} /. solfwd1, {t, -100, 100}, PlotPoints -> {200000}] /. 
     Line[p_] :> {Thickness[0.0015], RGBColor["#396AB1"], Arrowheads[{0., 0., 0., 0.}], Arrow[p]}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False]
```

Comment: Your equations are stiff. That means one of the functions (Psi) changes very fast compared to the other functions. Maybe it even diverges. Try if you can start from -100.

Comment: Thank you, Daniel. If you see my code, I am indeed starting time from -100. Do you mean something else when you say start from -100?

Comment: Yes, I mean you specify the initial values at zero.

Comment: I am sorry, I am not getting what you are saying. I have given the initial condition at time t=0. Do you mean I need to take non zero initial condition?

Comment: You start at zero and then integrate forwards and backwards. Try if you can give initial values at -100 and integrate forwards.

Comment: I have tried integrating time forward and backwards separately, but it didn't work. I will try giving initial condition at t=-100.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that time reversal is not an invarinance operation on this system. Assuming it is an Euler equation of motion, the time reversal operates by f'[-t] -> -f[t], f''[-t]->f[t]

Then you have, with slighly changed numeric parameters for readability

```
Gj[t_] = ({\[Phi][t], \[Theta][t], \[Psi][t]} /. 
 NDSolve[{19361/2 Sin[2 \[Theta][t]] Sin[2 \[Phi][t]] == 
    1250 (-((83 Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t])/2) - 
       17/3 (-2 Sin[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][
            t] (-3 Cos[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
             2 Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]) - 
          10 (\[Theta]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t])), 
   8/3 (-Derivative[1][\[Theta]][
          t] (-8 Cos[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] + 
          2 Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]) + 
       5 Sin[\[Theta][t]] (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[t]) == 0, 
   21/4 (Sin[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Theta]][t] Derivative[
         1][\[Phi]][t] + 
       Cos[\[Theta][t]] (\[Phi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
         t] + (\[Psi]^\[Prime]\[Prime])[
        t]) == -5 (-(1/3) Cos[\[Theta][t]] + 
       Cos[\[Theta][t]] Derivative[1][\[Phi]][t] - 
       Derivative[1][\[Psi]][t]), \[Phi][0] == \[Pi]/
    4, \[Theta][0] == \[Pi]/4, \[Psi][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][\[Phi]][0] == 0, 
   Derivative[1][\[Theta]][0] == 1/20, 
   Derivative[1][\[Psi]][0] == 0}, {\[Theta][t], \[Phi][
    t], \[Psi][t]}, {t, 0, 100}, MaxSteps -> 100000, 
  AccuracyGoal -> 6])[[1]];

NDSolve::mxst: Maximum number of 100000 steps reached at the point t == 12.957834322250367`.
```

The trace of unit 3-leg on the unit sphere shows a spiraling in of the 3-axis to the north pole

```
Show[ ( ParametricPlot3D[
 Evaluate[EulerMatrix[Gj[t]]] . IdentityMatrix[3][[#1]], {t, 0, 
  7}, PlotStyle -> #2] &) @@@ {{1, Red}, {2, Green}, {3, Blue}}]
```

[image: axis 3-leg movement]

Comment: Thank you, Roland. Can you give a little bit more explanation about this?

Comment: The equation is a second order  ODE system for three angles with reactive forces that seem to be very complicated. Unless the forces are derivatives of a common potential function and the first derivatives represent Coriolis forces orthogonal to the velocities, the system will not be conservative. 

Conservative means that the total energy of the sum of squares of velocities plus the potential is constant in time. If not, the time backward will explode the velocities if the forward solution appoaches a rest state. Without thorougly analysis this question cannot be answered.